# how to create calculated column within python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am still new to writing code in Python.  working on a project where I want to convert a column's values to a different set of values.  Example: Column 'Duration' has a list of whole integers to represent seconds and I want to convert to minutes.  Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(r"doc.csv", header=0)
new_df=df.dropna()
new_df.eval(['Tripduration']/60) #gives error
new_df['Tripduration']=new_df['Tripduration'].map(lambda Tripduration: Tripduraation/60) # gives error
```

I'm stumped.  would appreciate some help.  Thanks.  hope this makes sense

Comment: Please share input and output samples of the df

Comment: `new_df['Tripduration'] = new_df['Tripduration']/60`. You don't need eval or map or anything, basically just treat it as you would a 1d numpy array; simple math operation are vectorized.

Comment: An aside, your second one _would_ work, but it's super inefficient so you shouldn't use it. You just have a typo where when you reference the variable you have an extra 'a'.

Comment: Just tried that and I'm getting an error: "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.  Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `reset_index` after `dropna`.
2. Just use simple math operations on the Column

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Tripduration': [213, 324, 123, 45, 67, None, 123]})

new_df = df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
new_df['Tripduration'] = new_df['Tripduration'] / 60

print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   Tripduration
0      3.550000
1      5.400000
2      2.050000
3      0.750000
4      1.116667
5      2.050000
```

---

`copy` can be used instead of `reset_index` if the indexes are important:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Tripduration': [213, 324, 123, 45, 67, None, 123]})

new_df = df.dropna().copy()
new_df['Tripduration'] = new_df['Tripduration'] / 60

print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   Tripduration
0      3.550000
1      5.400000
2      2.050000
3      0.750000
4      1.116667
6      2.050000
```